# Cleaning away symbols/whitespace efficiently

Tags: python, regex, string, replace, data-cleaning

I have strings such as `"- memphis , tn! "`, `"~~~memphis,tn"`, `":) memphis , tn (:"`, `". - memphis,tn - ."`, `"memphis tn?"`. I want to clean each of these strings such that each string becomes `"memphis,tn"`. Currently, I use the code below, but is there a more efficient way of doing this? Perhaps using regex?

Note that I currently have the issue that the ordering of the special characters affects the end result. For instance, `". - memphis,tn - ."` gives the right result, whereas `"- . memphis,tn . -"` does not. This is not intended. If it could be fixed as a sideeffect, that would be great!

The strings are pure ASCII and I may be tempted to remove more special characters than the ones below.

**Edit:**
Sorry, I should note that not all strings have the "x,y" format. Also strings such as "-- New York City --" or "* Texas *" should be cleaned up.

```
# remove emoticons
smileys = [":)",":\\",":(",";)",
           "(:","\\:","):","(;"]
for s in smileys:
    loc = loc.replace(s, '')

# cleaning whitespace uses
loc = ' '.join(loc.split())
loc = loc.strip()
loc = loc.replace(' ,', ',')
loc = loc.replace(', ', ',')
loc = loc.replace(' .', '.')
loc = loc.replace('. ', '.')

# clean special symbols off the sides
symbols = '.,!-#~*^?@" '
loc = loc.strip(symbols)
```

Comment: what will be output for `"-- New York City --"`?

Comment: the how are you replacing the spaces in `:) memphis , tn (:`?

Comment: Ah, yes I use .strip() again after removing special characters. Sorry.

Comment: `str.strip` accepts a string of a bunch of characters and strips them off in any order for instance: `"asdfdsas hello fdsafsdf".strip("asdf") -> ' hello '`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
','.join(y for y in re.split("[- ,!~?]", x) if y)
                                ^^
                                ||
                    List all the symbols here
```

*Python Code*

```
y = ["- memphis , tn! ", "~~~memphis,tn", ":) memphis , tn (:", ". - memphis,tn - .", "memphis tn?", ". - memphis,tn - .", "- . memphis,tn . -"]

for x in y:
    print(','.join(y for y in re.split("[- ,!~?:;)(.]", x) if y))
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/UQxGro)**

If you want to remove any symbol other than alphanumeric, you can use

```
print(','.join(y for y in re.split("_|[^\w]", x) if y))
```

Comment: `if len(y)>0` can be simplified to just `if y` since the boolean-ness of zero length sequences is False and any sequence with stuff in it is True.